# Contact form PHP script doesnt load?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

So I am trying to build a contact form using html and a php script. I have done this in the past (with templates) and all seem fine however I tried creating one on my own and for some reasons it isnt loading the script when submitting it on the html page (the form action etc is all correct) Im guessing it must be sometihng to do with the php please see the code below. Any help would be greatful:

```
   <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "text@email.co.uk";

    $email_subject = "Test form";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['teamname']) ||

        !isset($_POST['yourname']) ||

        !isset($_POST['secondname']) ||

        !isset($_POST['address']) ||

        !isset($_POST['postcode']) ||

        !isset($_POST['youremail']) ||

        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['otherplayername1']) ||

        !isset($_POST['otherplayername2']) ||

        !isset($_POST['otherplayername3']) ||

        !isset($_POST['otherplayername4']) ||

        !isset($_POST['otherplayername5']) ||

        !isset($_POST['otherplayername6']) ||

        !isset($_POST['otherplayername7']) ||

        !isset($_POST['location']) ||

 {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $teamname = $_POST['teamname']; // required

    $yourname = $_POST['yourname']; // required

    $secondname = $_POST['secondname']; // not required

    $address = $_POST['address']; // not required

    $postcode = $_POST['postcode']; // required

    $your-email = $_POST['youremail']; // required

    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // not required


    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$youremail)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$yourname)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$teamname)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Team Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$postcode)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Post Code you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }


    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($teamname)."\n";

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($yourname)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($secondname)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Postcode: ".clean_string($postcode)."\n";

    $email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($youremail)."\n";

    $email_message .= "phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "other player 1: ".clean_string($otherplayername1)."\n";

    $email_message .= "other player 2: ".clean_string($otherplayername2)."\n";

    $email_message .= "other player 3: ".clean_string($otherplayername3)."\n";

    $email_message .= "other player 4: ".clean_string($otherplayername4)."\n";

    $email_message .= "other player 5: ".clean_string($otherplayername5)."\n";

    $email_message .= "other player 6: ".clean_string($otherplayername6)."\n";

    $email_message .= "other player 7: ".clean_string($otherplayername7)."\n";



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
You can choose to play either on the day or through Paypal (please bring your Paypal reference with you on the match day)



<?php

}

?>
```

EDIT: Updated Php and added html

Here is also my html form:

```
 <form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact.php">

<input type="text" name="teamname" value="" size="40" placeholder="Team Name"/><br>
<input type="text" name="yourname" value="" size="40" placeholder="Your Name"/><br>
<input type="text" name="secondname" value="" size="40" placeholder="Last Name"/><br>
<input type="text" name="address" value="" size="40" placeholder="Address"/><br>
<input type="text" name="postcode" value="" size="40" placeholder="Postcode"/><br>
<input type="email" name="youremail" value="" size="40" placeholder="Email"/><br>
<input type="tel" name="phone" value="" size="40" placeholder="Phone Number"/><br>
</div>

<input type="text" name="otherplayername1" value="" size="40" placeholder="Other Players Name 1"/><br>
<input type="text" name="otherplayername2" value="" size="40" placeholder="Other Players Name 2"/><br>
<input type="text" name="otherplayername3" value="" size="40" placeholder="Other Players Name 3"/><br>
<input type="text" name="otherplayername4" value="" size="40" placeholder="Other Players Name 4"/><br>
<input type="text" name="otherplayername5" value="" size="40" placeholder="Other Players Name 5"/><br>
<input type="text" name="otherplayername6" value="" size="40" placeholder="Other Players Name 6"/><br>
<input type="text" name="otherplayername7" value="" size="40" placeholder="Other Players Name 7"/><br>
<input type="text" name="location" value="" size="40"  placeholder="Location"/></span><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" /> <a target="_blank" style="color: #fff;">I confirm that I accept the Cash Leagues Rules and Regulations.</a>
<input type="submit" value="Send" action="contact.php"/></form>
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: it just loads a blank screen no error or sucess message

Comment: See my answer ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/29895760/3394281

Comment: @DushyantJoshi The `died` function is defined within the script. And `$your_email` doesn't exist either, it should be `$youremail`.

Comment: Your if statement's syntax is wrong,  You have used $your-email not $your_email. @Siguza,corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$team-name = $_POST['team-name']; // required
$your-name = $_POST['your-name']; // required
$second-name = $_POST['second-name']; // not required
$your-email = $_POST['your-email']; // required
```

Don't use "-" in var-names:

```
$team-name -> $teamname
$your-name -> $yourname
...
```

And turn on error_reporting, when you developing to see all erros php give you :) (in this case: Parse error)

Second problem:
You check for `$_POST['email']`, if it is set, if not, you doing nothing. But in your form, there is no input field with this name, so your script never do anything.

Comment: Hi I have taken out all the '-' and also edited the form however im still recieivng a blank screen upon hitting submit?

Comment: Why you changed the names on your form? You have to change the variable name in your php script only ;) Have you enabled error_reporting to see any other errors? Can you post your form, too?

Comment: turn on `error_reporting`. write in the beginning `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Added the form and upadted php script :)

Comment: oh ok shall i just remove $_POST['email'] then?

Comment: I don't know, you should at least use the correct name of the field (i assume "youremail"). And you should handle (in an else branch) what happens, if the e-mail field is missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

The character `-` is not allowed in variables names.
Try replacing lines like

```
$team-name = $_POST['team-name']; // required
```

with

```
$team_name = $_POST['team-name']; // required
```

In PHP, a valid variable name starts with a letter or an underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. No `-` character is allowed. This is because otherwise there would be an ambiguity with the maths operation `-`.

You can find a detailed explanation in the [official documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

As a general hint, anyway, I strongly suggest you to carefully read the error message produced by PHP (and report it together with the source code, when asking for a help on StackOverflow): PHP, like almost all the programming languages out there, is pretty informative in case of a failure. If you read the error message, it is very likely that it tells you **what** the problem is and **where** it has been found (that is, typically, the line number). For example, a typical PHP error message could be

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function my_function()
in /home/mysite/public_html/test.php on line 2
```

where `Call to undefined function my_function()` is the problem and `/home/mysite/public_html/test.php` plus `line 2` give you an information on the problem position.

In case your script didn't give you enough information, please, refer to the [Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) page in the manual: it contains precious information on how to improve details in error messages.